# Make function have ellipsis for arguments in help() function

Tags: python, docstring

If you type `help(vars)`, the following is produced:

```
vars(...)
    vars([object]) -> dictionary

    Without arguments, equivalent to locals().
    With an argument, equivalent to object.__dict__.
```

When I do the following:

```
def func(x, y): pass

help(func)
```

it displays this:

```
func(x, y)
```

How can I change it so that it shows up with `...` between the parentheses like the built-in function `vars()`?  (That is, `func(...)`)

**Edit**: It has been suggested to use a docstring, but that won't do what I want.  Here is an example:

```
def func(x, y):
    """func(...) -> None"""

help(func)
```

result:

```
func(x, y)
    func(...) -> None
```

You see, `x, y` is still being displayed instead of `...`

Comment: Give the function a `__doc__` attribute (docstring).

Comment: That isn't quite the same thing.  I'll edit my question to show you.

Comment: I think that that is not posible or at least is not that easy, some of the build-in functions have that because they are write in C so they escape the usual mechanism that the _help_ function use

Comment: Starting [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/pydoc.py#L1352), you can see the conditions under which `pydoc.TextDoc.docroutine` (in Python 3.5, anyway) uses `(...)` to represent the signature of a callable.

Comment: A quick test shows that `xxx(...)` is the case for all the built-in functions. Following the hint from @chepner's comment, I looked to see what `inspect.getargspec(len)` returns, but it throws a TypeError with the message `TypeError: <built-in function len> is not a Python function`. So it looks like any Python function *will* have an argspec, and so will get displayed with the args listed in their help. Short of implementing your `func` in C, it may not be possible to get this elliptical output.

Comment: Just curious: Why would you _want_ this?

Comment: @tobias_k: I really don't expect every to use it, but I'm "just curious".

Comment: But then, shouldn't the question actually be "why do build-in function show `(...)` in `help`?" instead of "how can I replicate this?"

Comment: @tobias_k: I'm not sure why.  What I am wondering is how I can replicate it.  I don't expect to use that information, but I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have (at least) two alternatives to achieve what you want.

The best alternative would be to override the `__str__` method of the `inspect.Signature` class. However, as it is written in C, it is read only.

So to do that you need to extend the class as following:

```
class MySignature(inspect.Signature):
  def __str__(self):
    return '(...)'
```

then after defining your function you execute:

```
func_signature = inspect.signature(func)
func.__signature__ = MySignature(func_signature.parameters.values(), 
                                 return_annotation=func_signature.return_annotation)
```

which would then return the following for `help(func)`:

```
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(...)
(END)
```

With this approach inspect.signature still works:

```
In [1]: inspect.signature(func)
Out[1]: <MySignature (...)>
```

Alternatively if you don't really care about being able to properly introspect your function (and probably some other use cases), then you can  define the value of your function's `__signature__` to an object which is not a `Signature` instance:

```
def func(x, y):
    pass

func.__signature__ = object()

help(func)
```

generates the result:

```
Help on function func in module __main__:

func(...)
(END)
```

But now `inspect.signature(func)` will raise `TypeError: unexpected object <object object at 0x10182e200> in __signature__ attribute`.

Note: this last version is quite hacky and I would not recommend it.

For more info on these two techniques and how the signature works see [PEP 0362](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/).

**Update:**
For python 2.7 you can do the following (probably better using a mock framework):

```
In [1]: import inspect

In [2]: def myformatargspec(*args, **kwargs):
   ...:     return '(...)'
   ...:

In [3]: def func(x, y):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [6]: inspect.formatargspec = myformatargspec

In [7]: help(func)

Help on function func in module __main__:

func(...)
(END)
```